# how do i store the output of my cursor object to a text file?

Tags: python, file-io, sqlite

I have accessed a database and have the result in a cursor object. when I try to save it to a text file, python says

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not sqlite3.Cursor
```

can someone tell me what I should do here?

```
curobject.execute('select * from device_auth')  
for row in curobject:  
        print row  
myfile =open('out.txt', 'w')  
myfile.write(curobject)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just write objects to a file, you have to either [serialize](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) them or write your own string representation of the object. For records of a database the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module could make sense.

Which approach is better depends on what you want to do with the file later.

Comment: i am not sure bout choosing the right approach since i'm fairly new to python.. here's what i want to do. After storing the output, i'll have to compare it with another output that i stored elsewhere..  
pls guide me the suitable one..

Answer (score 1):

For example something like this:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(', '.join(row) + '\n' for row in curobject)    # assuming row of strings
```

Comment: hi.. what would be the best way to store the output in my case? as i want to compare it with another output?  
and btw, thanks for the edit ;)